# Kotlin Activity memory leak

Tags: android, memory-leaks, kotlin

I just write a Activity use Kotlin,it's very sample,The code below:

```
package com.chiquedoll.chiquedoll.view.activity
import android.os.Bundle
import com.chiquedoll.chiquedoll.R
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.view_normal_toolbar.*

/**
 * Created by super-zuo on 17-12-12.
 * Description:
 */
class TestActivity : BaseActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_profile)
        tv_title.text = getString(R.string.edit_profile)
        tv_right.text = getString(R.string.save)
    }
}
```

Here is my BaseActivity code:

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ActivityModule activityModule;
    private ViewDataBinding indicatorBinding;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            BaseApplication.mSession = (MSession) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("mSession");
            if (BaseApplication.mSession != null && BaseApplication.mSession.customer != null) {
                HeadInterceptor.setUserId(BaseApplication.mSession.customer.id);
                HeadInterceptor.setAccessToken(BaseApplication.mSession.getAccessToken());
            }
        }
        getApplicationComponent().inject(this);
    }

    protected ApplicationComponent getApplicationComponent() {
        return ((BaseApplication) getApplication()).getApplicationComponent();
    }

    protected ActivityModule getActivityModule() {
        if (activityModule == null) {
            return new ActivityModule(this);
        }
        return activityModule;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            BaseApplication.mSession = (MSession) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("mSession");
            if (BaseApplication.mSession != null && BaseApplication.mSession.customer != null) {
                HeadInterceptor.setUserId(BaseApplication.mSession.customer.id);
                HeadInterceptor.setAccessToken(BaseApplication.mSession.getAccessToken());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        Log.e("SaveInstanceState", "yes");
        outState.putSerializable("mSession", BaseApplication.mSession);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

}
```

When i close the activity,the LeakCanary tell me the activity has been leaked. some one can help me? When I use EditText, TextInputEditText will also leak Activity.
[image]

Comment: Can you post your `BaseActivity`?

Comment: I  post my BaseActivity. Maybe it not be the reason.

Comment: It is possible this might not be caused by your application, but it might be a platform leak refferenced here in this issue... https://github.com/square/leakcanary/issues/890